# Ubuntu change the passphrase on a ecryptfs home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, passwords, ecryptfs

I'm having some trouble with ecryptfs. Here's what's happened so far:

1. I had an encrypted home directory, via ecryptfs. It worked fine.
2. I changed my username and moved my home directory. Porting the home directory was a bit of a pain, but went fine (more-or-less following the steps discussed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871122)).
3. I then had a new username and a newly named home directory and everything was working smoothly for a time.
4. I then change my password. Now ubuntu won't let me log in from the GUI any more, because my new password no longer decrypts the home directory. I can drop into a tty and `ecryptfs-mount-private` or whatever, and it works, but it requires my *old* password.

I conjecture that everything would work fine if I could get ecryptfs to require my new password. However, I don't know how to get ecryptfs to recognize my new password (and I know that on home directories, it's doing something fancy that's supposed to allow me to change my user password, where the correspondence was presumably broken by my changing my username). How do I get an ecryptfs *of my home directory which has since been renamed* to respond to an updated user password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what the [ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase) command is designed for.

Comment: great, thanks! (I was worried that the username change would throw a wrench in things, but I assume from your comment that I don't need to worry about it.)